# Adding a node inside didMoveToView does not appear, however having same code for multiple elements works as expected

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am confused as to why adding a shape node inside of didMoveToView give me no results, however when I call a function and perform the drawing there it renders fine.

Here is my code
-this example does not work

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    SKShapeNode *shape = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

    CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, NULL, self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares, self.sizeOfVerticalSquares);

    CGRect bound = CGRectMake(50, 50, self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares,self.sizeOfVerticalSquares);

    CGPathAddRect(myPath, NULL, bound);

    shape.path = myPath;


    [shape setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:.6 blue:.3 alpha:1.0]];

    [shape setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.3 blue:.8 alpha:0.2]];

    [shape setGlowWidth:1.0];

    [self addChild:shape];


}
```

-Here is the code that works with an array

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(UIView *)view
{

self.sizeOfVerticalSquares = 20;
self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares = 20;
[self configureSquire];
[self renderSquiares];

}

-(void)configureSquiare
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {


            SKShapeNode *shape = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];

            CGMutablePathRef myPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

            //CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, NULL, i*self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares, j*self.sizeOfVerticalSquares);

            CGRect bound = CGRectMake(self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares, self.sizeOfVerticalSquares, self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares,self.sizeOfVerticalSquares);

            CGPathAddRect(myPath, NULL, bound);

            shape.path = myPath;

            [self.squares addObject:shape];

        }
    }




}

-(void)renderSquiares
{
    for(int i = 0; i < self.squares.count; i++)
    {
        [[self.squares objectAtIndex:i] setFillColor:(__bridge CGColorRef)[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:.6 blue:.3 alpha:1.0]];

        [[self.squares objectAtIndex:i] setStrokeColor:(__bridge CGColorRef)[UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.3 blue:.8 alpha:0.2]];

        [[self.squares objectAtIndex:i] setGlowWidth:1];

        [self addChild:[self.squares objectAtIndex:i]];

    }

}
```

Comment: Not a solution, but you should call `[super didMoveToView:view]` in both cases.

Comment: When is self.sizeOfHorizontalSquares set?  That could have been causing some issues.

Comment: Sorry I recreated the calls instead of copying and pasting. They are set right before the two calls

Comment: And the last section of code is the one that works..